# Node FFI call and dynamic lib generated from Rust

Tags: node.js, rust, ffi

I am trying to use node-ffi with dynamic lib generated from rust. This is the rust link, https://github.com/petrachor/pairing-ariel. How can I get JavaScript to properly call rust function and return the expected result?
To compile rust first change crate-type(Cargo.toml) to ["dylib"],  and `cargo build --release`

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ArrayStruct<T> {
    d: *mut T,
    len: usize,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn g2_get_one(g: ArrayStruct<u8>) -> bool {
    return panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        g2_to_raw(G2Affine::get_generator(), g);
    }).is_ok();
}
```

My node code to call rust via FFI

```
var ref = require('ref');
var FFI = require('ffi');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');

//var IArrayType = require('ref-array');

var ArrayStruct8 = Struct({
    'd': "uchar*",
    'len': "int32"
});

var lib = new FFI.Library('target/release/libpairing', { 'g2_get_zero': [ ref.types.bool, [ ArrayStruct8] ]});

var buf = new Buffer.alloc(192);
var a8 = new ArrayStruct8({d: buf, len: 192});

lib.g2_get_zero(a8);
console.dir(a8);
```

I was expecting a8.b to contain unsigned char* .. When I did `console.log(a8.d)`, I got "@". There is something out there I have not fixed yet, please help me.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, I have responded to your question? How do one rightly play with `unsigned char*`?

Comment: Surely `g` (the argument of your FFI function) should not be an owned type there (`g: ArrayStruct<u8>` as opposed to a mutable reference); I've never done node-rust FFI so I'm not entirely certain that's an eyebrow-raising moment, but it feels like one

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, But when a static library is made from it(rust) and included into a C++ (path)file it worked.. https://github.com/petrachor/petrachor/blob/master/libdevcrypto/BLS12_381.cpp

Comment: That is some seriously convoluted stuff, masking that pointer in an owned struct.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, I am aware of `move` ... But I mentioned that it works when it is compiled as static lib , and linked via include path for c++ compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199509/discussion-between-user618677-and-sebastien-renauld).

Comment: Why should someone delete virtually all my comments, what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 0):

This will get edited once I am at home and have my full set of tools available to get the actual, `struct`-based example to work.

The symptoms across the FFI boundary with the implementation given in the question are as follows:

- Pointer integrity is kept (the same pointer surfaces on both sides of the FFI boundary)
- Buffer integrity is **not** kept or updated. Coming from Rust to NodeJS, the buffer should have been updated, but is not

The quick solution when dealing with low-field-count modification structures like this is to pass a fat pointer instead (pointer + length) as follows, for instance:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn do_something_with_array(buf: *mut u8, len: u32) -> u32 {
    unsafe {
        buf.write_bytes(1, 3);
    }
    3
}
```

With the corresponding FFI definition across on the nodeJS front:

```
var lib = new FFI.Library('target/debug/libtest2', {
  'do_something_with_array': [ 'int', ['pointer', 'int'] ]
});

var buf = new Buffer.alloc(192);
var new_len = lib.do_something_with_array(buf, 192);
var new_buf = buf.slice(0, new_len);
```

It seems like `ref-struct` requires a sync of some sort as the underlying memory *has the right content*.

Comment: Waiting for your struct version

Comment: Looks like I have solved this issue. I post my answer later.

Comment: Please do; I've been swamped with other projects meanwhile :-(

Comment: Renauld, Please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to figure out how to get Buffer integrity kept or updated I noticed that I do not really need ref-struct or something complex. I think I am making use of C language internal layout of struct. Just pointer and it's length. For example,

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ArrayStruct<T> {
    d: *mut T,
    len: usize,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn g2_get_one(g: ArrayStruct<u8>) -> bool {
    return panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        g2_to_raw(G2Affine::get_generator(), g);
    }).is_ok();
}
```

To call the `g2_get_one` from Nodejs do the following:

```
var lib = new FFI.Library('target/debug/libtest2', {
  'do_something_with_array': [ 'int', ['pointer', 'int'] ]
});

var buf = new Buffer.alloc(192);
var new_len = lib.do_something_with_array(buf, 192);
```

As long as one follows this simple rule you can have multiple structs as parameters in Rust and this rule would be obeyed .